# “Find to her cost”

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

> Woe would befall anyone who sought to sully the good name of Windsor dynasty, as Daisy Warwick, one of Edward VII’s mistresses, ***found to her cost***.

The whole context is such:

> Woe would befall anyone who sought to sully the good name of Windsor dynasty, as Daisy Warwick, one of Edward VII’s mistresses, ***found to her cost***. Daisy Warwick who probably was the most important of Edward VII’s mistresses, told the advisors that she is going to publish a large amount of letters, she was trying to blackmail George V. She wanted to be paid 100,000 pounds. This provokes total panic amongst the Royal advisors. Effectively, what happens is that the Royal solicitor serves her with a sort of notice that she’s going to be committed to Holloway prison unless she shuts up.

What does ***found to her cost*** mean, and what might be the grammatical structure?

Comment: Very closely-related on ELL: [What is the meaning of "to learn to one's cost"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27775/what-is-the-meaning-of-to-learn-to-ones-cost)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is an idiomatic expression meaning:

***[to someone's cost](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to_someone%27s_cost)***:

> With loss or disadvantage to someone.
>
> - ‘without programmes to play on it, the cleverest machine is useless—as some hardware manufacturers already know to their cost’

Also: [at someone’s expense](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at_someone%27s_expense)

ODO

Comment: please don't answer questions that should be migrated to ELL

Comment: FWIW it seems benny was just confused about the "found" with no comma

Comment: it's not idiomatic in any way, suggest please edit the answer maybe?  the usual first definition of idiom is "a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words".  (Example, "over the moon".)  "To someone'e cost" is just a completely clear phrase, if you had (for some bizarre reason) never heard it before it makes complete sense, as any other English sentence.

Comment: (I appreciate that *idiom* is sometimes used to mean "a common phrase", but surely on ELL of all places, it is worth keeping a stricter meaning of idiom, and just calling "common phrases" "common phrases".   :O  So there. )

Comment: Hello, what does *ODO* mean?

Answer (score 8):

"...as she learned, to her detriment."

She found out that it was a bad idea, and "to her cost" means that the learning of that lesson cost her something. You can find equivalent phrases using "surprise", "dismay", "consternation", "chagrin", and "detriment".
It might be a shortening of "...leading to..."?

Comment: Please cite your sources.